# Test for nonlinearity in cross-sectional time series data in R

Tags: r, time-series, hypothesis-testing, nonlinear-regression, cross-section

I have a cross sectional time series dataset that looks like this:

```
Country    Year    X1
France     2008    1
France     2009    2
France     2010    3
France     2011    4
France     2012    5
Germany    2008    1
Germany    2009    2
Germany    2010    3
Germany    2011    4
Germany    2012    5
```

Is there a simple approach to determining with a hypothesis test whether a linear or nonlinear regression is most appropriate for modeling X1's relationship with time? Solution within R is preferred. Thank you.